# child_process quitting when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have a node app, using child_process to wget a very large file. Despite setting the relevant options (or so I thought, it just seems to terminate with reason 'null' immediately. If I run the command manually it's fine. (The .js / event thread continues to run, so it's not that. '...' is redacted URL)

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var options = {stdio: 'ignore', detatched: true};

var ls = spawn('wget', ['http://...', '-O', './file.sav'], options);
console.log("PID is ", ls.pid);
ls.unref();
```

Comment: It looks like you want to start the `wget` and then allow the Node process (but not the `wget` process) to exit ("backgrounding" the `wget`). Is that your intent? Also, you mistyped _"detached"_.

Comment: Have corrected the spelling now! Yes, that's exactly right. What happens in node is largely irrelevant as I manage the process later via the PID..

Comment: But it's still not leaving the process running, despite correcting the spelling @robertklep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. I was running pm2 (process manager) in watch mode. This was restarting the Node app each time wget started writing to the disk!

It's interesting that this was happening at the start of the write to the disk, rather than waiting for wget to finish writing the file. Also that it was so quick that even though the code unrefs the process, this wasn't happening in time to save the process from ending with the Node app.

Got round the problem by excluding the directories that are being written to in the config of pm2.